# 32 bit operating system but x64 processor?

Tags: .net, x86, x86-64, processor

Is it possible to have "32 bit operating system" running on "64 bit processor" ?

What happens when I target my runtime in .net to x-64 and my OS is 32 bit  ?

One more to add "by the way what is meant by 32 bit OS (vs 32 bit processor)" ?

Comment: "64 bit processor"? NO. x86_64 processor? YES, since it's just a x86 extension. Not all 64-bit architectures are extension of 32-bit ones (E.g. Itanium, MMIX...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes; the x64 processor is just an extension of x86, which is a 32-bit processor.
2. It will not run.
3. It means the OS contains code for running on a 32-bit processor.

Comment: Although x86_64 is a "extended" x86 architecture, its a *different* architecture. This means that 32 bit programs will just not run in x86_64 mode. You need the 32 bit compatibility mode for that (which does exist on each x86_64 so far, but that may change in the future), in which the processor behaves just like a good old x86 outside the kernel.